# Are these two set theory statements equivalent?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

does $B - (A \cup C) = B \cup (A' \cup C')$?

Comment: $\cup\setminus$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: To render the math you use dollar signs `$` and symbols like setminus are used with backslash `\`. I've edited your post - is this what you originally wanted to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  To see that this is not true, take $$M=\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g\}$$ as the mother set and $A=\{a,b\}, B=\{a,c,d\}, C=\{c,e\}$ and evaluate both sides of your so-called equation. For giving a formal set theatrical fact use @Martin's answer.

Comment: I thought that B -(AUC) meant exist in B, but not in A or C?

Comment: hmmm any trick to remember that? because the use of - here is not very intuitive

Comment: @MathildaPitt: Your thought was right. $B-(A\cup C)$ contains those elements which are in $B$ but not in $(A\cup C)$

Comment: yeah nevermind $B \cap U -(A \cup C) = B$

Comment: @MathildaPitt: $(B\cap U)-(A\cup B)$ or $B\cap (U-(A\cup B))$?

Comment: the former B $\cup$  U gives B right?

Comment: @MathildaPitt: The union of the mother set $U$ and any subset of it, say $B$ is always the whole set $U$, but the intersection is always the small set.

Answer (score 2):

$B-(A\cup C)=B\cap(A\cup C)'$ (this is basically the definition)

$(A\cup C)'=A'\cap C'$ (by [de Morgan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws))

Hence $B-(A\cup C)=B\cap A'\cap C'$.

Comment: I thought that B -(AUC) meant exist in B, but not in A or C?

Comment: $X\setminus Y$ denotes the [relative complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29) or difference of two sets. It consists of elements which belong to $X$ but not to $Y$. In this case $x$ belongs to $B\setminus(A\cup C)$ if it belongs to $B$ and it doesn't belong to $A\cup C$. Which is the same thing as you wrote. An it is the same thing as saying that $x$ belongs to $B$ and to the complement of $A\cup C$, i.e. $x\in B\cap (A\cup C)'$.